# Can you tell me what Python library I should use for real-time image noise cancellation coding?

Tags: python

I'm listening to a video lecture and I'm having a lot of noise in the video, so I'd like to

1. deliver the voice to the virtual speaker in real time,
2. remove the noise from the virtual speaker,
3. and then transfer the adjusted sound to the real speaker.

please tell me what Python library to make this

I try using WASAPI to make virtual speaker, but I failed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.